# sync two mysql database for two remote machine

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Any solutions can sync two mysql database for two remote machine? i have to sync periodically

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) with master-master or master-slave.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want a one-way sync - if you need to go several ways, you need to have conflict resolution, which is nontrivial and most solutions don't do that.

mk-table-sync or "rubyrep" are two systems I know of which will synchronise data with another database. Read their documentation for more information.

MySQL replication is ok in specific cases, but tricky to set up and requires very careful monitoring etc, as it can become out of sync and will not automatically re-sync. You can also only do replication FROM one server (but TO multiple servers).

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-cluster-for-two-servers.html

Comment: MySQL cluster is probably not suitable for what the OP requires due to its synchronous replication and high operational overhead.